# Alternative to the `c()` function that works with pipes in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

A workaround to use `c()` with the pipe operator is to add curly brackets

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% {
  c(.$mpg, .$cyl)
}
```

But it's not pretty.

Is there alternative to the `c` function that works with pipes in R?

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  alternative_c(.$mpg, .$cyl) # Does such a function exist?
```

Comment: You want `select(mpg, cyl)`?

Comment: It's just a toy example. My code does not involve columns of a dataframe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `magrittr` exposition pipe `%$%` you could do:

```r
library(magrittr)

mtcars %$% c(mpg, cyl)
#>  [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4
#> [16] 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7
#> [31] 15.0 21.4  6.0  6.0  4.0  6.0  8.0  6.0  8.0  4.0  4.0  6.0  6.0  8.0  8.0
#> [46]  8.0  8.0  8.0  8.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  8.0  8.0  8.0  8.0  4.0  4.0  4.0
#> [61]  8.0  6.0  8.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to pipe into `with()`:

```
mtcars %>% 
   with(c(mpg, cyl))

 [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2
[24] 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4  6.0  6.0  4.0  6.0  8.0  6.0  8.0  4.0  4.0  6.0  6.0  8.0  8.0  8.0
[47]  8.0  8.0  8.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  8.0  8.0  8.0  8.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  8.0  6.0  8.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with an anonymous function

```r
mtcars %>% 
  (\(.) c(.$mpg, .$cyl))

 [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3
[25] 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4  6.0  6.0  4.0  6.0  8.0  6.0  8.0  4.0  4.0  6.0  6.0  8.0  8.0  8.0  8.0  8.0
[49]  8.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  8.0  8.0  8.0  8.0  4.0  4.0  4.0  8.0  6.0  8.0  4.0
```